# Enable an input type of image inside a hyperlink with knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I show a hyperlink with an input type of image. The button should be disabled by default and when a certain condition is true the button should be enabled via knockoutjs enable binding.

But this will not prevent the user from executing the hyperlink.

How can I do this?

```
<a class="areaLink" href="/Module/Create" id="CreateModule">
<input src="/Content/Images/createmodule.png" title="Create module" type="image">
</a>

 $('#CreateModule').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // do something
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it in a hyperlink as input will have its own events which you can bind to. Give the input an ID and use this to bind a click and do the enabling.

Comment: you were right, fine. The input with id and bind the click even on it and with default disabled="disabled". Then knockout enables the input when the condition is true :) thanks.